# wave equation for a homegeneous prism object

Tags: refraction

Are there  any textbooks showing how to get the solution to Maxwell's equation of a uniform prism object with refractive index n? I'm asking because I want to see the explicit connection between wave equation and refraction.

Comment: In the 3 dimensional case, any serious book on optics shohuld include it. The key topic here is the Fresnel equations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations keep in mind these equations are for solving the wave equation in three dimensions. The two dimensional case will be simpler.

Comment: Thanks. I know Fresnel approximation can be used to propagate scalar field. But when you talk about scalar field, you assume some terms in Maxwell's equation can be discarded. Actually my question is since they all come from Maxwell's equation, why not just starting from the origin and do approximations where needed.